# Transparently encoding/decoding `$` and `.` when inserting/retrieving documents in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, escaping, pymongo

I'm working on an API written in Python that accepts JSON payloads from clients, applies some validation and stores the payloads in MongoDB so that they can be processed asynchronously.

However, I'm running into some trouble with payloads that (legitimately) include keys that start with `$` and/or include `.`.  [According to the MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/faq/developers/#dollar-sign-operator-escaping), my best bet is to escape these characters:

> In some cases, you may wish to build a BSON object with a user-provided key. In these situations, keys will need to substitute the reserved `$` and `.` characters. Any character is sufficient, but consider using the Unicode full width equivalents: `U+FF04` (i.e. “＄”) and `U+FF0E` (i.e. “．”).

Fair enough, but here's where it gets interesting.  I'd like this process to be transparent to the application, so:

- The keys should be unescaped when retrieving the documents...
- *...but only keys that needed to be escaped in the first place.*

For example, suppose a (nefarious) user sends a JSON payload that includes a key like `\ff04mixed.chars`.  When the application gets this document from the storage backend, this key should be converted back into `\ff04mixed.chars`, **not** `$mixed.chars`.

My primary concern here is information leakage; I don't want somebody to discover that the application requires special treatment for `$` and `.` characters.  The bad guys probably how to exploit MongoDB way better than I know how to secure it, and I don't want to take any chances.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I ended up going with:

- Before inserting a document into Mongo, run it through a `SONManipulator` that searches for and escapes any illegal keys in the document.

  - The original keys get stored as a separate attribute in the document so that we can restore them later.
- After retrieving a document from Mongo, run it through the `SONManipulator` to extract the original keys and restore them.

Here's an abbreviated example:

```
# Example of a document with naughty keys.
document = {
    '$foo': 'bar',
    '$baz': 'luhrmann'
}

##
# Before inserting the document, we must first run it through our
#   SONManipulator.
manipulator = KeyEscaper()
escaped = manipulator.transform_incoming(document, collection.name)

# Now we can insert the document.
document_id = collection.insert_one(escaped).inserted_id

##
# Later, we retrieve the document.
raw = collection.find_one({'_id': document_id})

# Run the document through our KeyEscaper to restore the original
#   keys.
unescaped = manipulator.transform_outgoing(raw, collection.name)

assert unescaped == document
```

The actual document stored in MongoDB looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId('582cebe5cd9b344c814d98e3')

  "__escaped__1": "luhrmann",
  "__escaped__0": "bar",

  "__escaped__": {
    "__escaped__1": ["$baz", {}],
    "__escaped__0": ["$foo", {}]
  }
}
```

Note the `__escaped__` attribute that contains the original keys so that they can be restored when the document is retrieved.

This makes querying against the escaped keys a little tricky, but that's infinitely preferable to not being able to store the document in the first place.

Full code with unit tests and example usage:
https://gist.github.com/todofixthis/79a2f213989a3584211e49bfba582b40